# How to cleanup hanging tasks on C# Task API?

Tags: c#, task

I have a simple function as the following:

```
    static Task<A> Peirce<A, B>(Func<Func<A, Task<B>>, Task<A>> a)
    {
        var aa = new TaskCompletionSource<A>();
        var tt = new Task<A>(() => 
            a(b =>
            {
                aa.SetResult(b);
                return new TaskCompletionSource<B>().Task;
            }).Result
        );
        tt.Start();
        return Task.WhenAny(aa.Task, tt).Result;
    }
```

The idea is simple: for any implementation of `a`, it must return a `Task<A>` to me. For this purpose, it may or may not use the parameter (of type `Func<A, Task<B>`). If it do, our callback will be called and it sets the result of `aa`, and then `aa.Task` will complete. Otherwise, the result of `a` will not depend on its parameter, so we simply return its value. In any of the situation, either `aa.Task` or the result of `a` will complete, so it should never block unless a do not uses its parameter and blocks, or the task returned by `a` blocks.

The above code works, for example

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<Func<int, Task<int>>, Task<int>> t = a =>
        {
            return Task.FromResult(a(20).Result + 10);
        };
        Console.WriteLine(Peirce(t).Result); // output 20
        t = a => Task.FromResult(10);
        Console.WriteLine(Peirce(t).Result); // output 10
    }
```

The problem here is, the two tasks `aa.Task` and `tt` must be cleaned up once the result of `WhenAny` has been determined, otherwise I am afraid there will be a leak of hanging tasks. I do not know how to do this, can any one suggest something? Or this is actually not a problem and C# will do it for me?

P.S. The name `Peirce` came from the famous "Peirce's Law"(`((A->B)->A)->A`) in propositional logic.

UPDATE: the point of matter is not "dispose" the tasks but rather stop them from running. I have tested, when I put the "main" logic in a 1000 loop it runs slowly (about 1 loop/second), and creates a lot of threads so it is a problem to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Bryan Crosby's answer, I can now implement the function as the following:

```
    private class CanceledTaskCache<A>
    {
        public static Task<A> Instance;
    }

    private static Task<A> GetCanceledTask<A>()
    {
        if (CanceledTaskCache<A>.Instance == null)
        {
            var aa = new TaskCompletionSource<A>();
            aa.SetCanceled();
            CanceledTaskCache<A>.Instance = aa.Task;
        }
        return CanceledTaskCache<A>.Instance;
    }

    static Task<A> Peirce<A, B>(Func<Func<A, Task<B>>, Task<A>> a)
    {
        var aa = new TaskCompletionSource<A>();
        Func<A, Task<B>> cb = b =>
        {
            aa.SetResult(b);
            return GetCanceledTask<B>();
        };
        return Task.WhenAny(aa.Task, a(cb)).Unwrap();
    }
```

and it works pretty well:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        {
            Func<Func<int, Task<String>>, Task<int>> t = 
                async a => (await a(20)).Length + 10;
            Console.WriteLine(Peirce(t).Result); // output 20
            t = async a => 10;
            Console.WriteLine(Peirce(t).Result); // output 10
        }
    }
```

Now it is fast and not consuming to much resources.  It can be even faster (about 70 times in my machine) if you do not use the async/await keyword:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        {
            Func<Func<int, Task<String>>, Task<int>> t =
                a => a(20).ContinueWith(ta => 
                    ta.IsCanceled ? GetCanceledTask<int>() : 
                    Task.FromResult(ta.Result.Length + 10)).Unwrap();
            Console.WriteLine(Peirce(t).Result); // output 20
            t = a => Task.FromResult(10);
            Console.WriteLine(Peirce(t).Result); // output 10
        }
    }
```

Here the matter is, even you can detected the return value of `a(20)`, there is no way to cancel the `async` block rather than throwing an `OperationCanceledException` and it prevents `WhenAny` to be optimized.

UPDATE: optimised code and compared async/await and native Task API.

UPDATE: If I can write the following code it will be ideal:

```
static Task<A> Peirce<A, B>(Func<Func<A, Task<B>>, Task<A>> a)
{
    var aa = new TaskCompletionSource<A>();
    return await? a(async b => {
        aa.SetResult(b);
        await break;
    }) : await aa.Task;
}
```

Here, `await? a : b` has value `a`'s result if a successes, has value b if a is cancelled (like `a ? b : c`, the value of `a`'s result should have the same type of b).
`await break` will cancel the current async block.

Answer (score 4):

A `Task` is a managed object.  Unless you are introducing unmanaged resources, you shouldn't worry about a `Task` leaking resources.  Let the GC clean it up and let the finalizer take care of the `WaitHandle`.

**EDIT:**

If you want to cancel tasks, consider using cooperative cancellation in the form of a `CancellationTokenSource`.  You can pass this token to any tasks via the overload, and inside of each task, you may have some code as follows:

```
while (someCondition)
{
    if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        break;
}
```

That way your tasks can gracefully clean up without throwing an exception.  However you can propogate an `OperationCancelledException` if you call `cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`.  So the idea in your case would be that whatever finishes first can issue the cancellation to the other tasks so that they aren't hung up doing work.

Comment: @EarthEngine: Updated my answer, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen Toub of MS Parallel Programming Team says:  ["No. Don't bother disposing of your tasks."](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx)

tldr: In most cases, disposing of a task does nothing, and when the task actually has allocated unmanaged resources, its finalizer will release them when the task object is collected.

Comment: In normal case, all task will complete normally or being canceled or there is thrown exceptions, and it is finally no longer running. I will not worry about disposing them in such a case. What I am concerning is, in my case, the task is still running even if the final result has been obtained. So I am actually looking for ways to stop them.